# Set searchView focused when activity opens android

Tags: android, kotlin, menu, searchview, oncreateoptionsmenu

I have a SearchActivity with a menu that holds a searchView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/searchMessageMenuItem"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        android:title="Search"
        app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
        app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView" />

</menu>
```

and inside onCreateOptionsMenu i get the searchView

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.search_message_menu, menu)
        searchView = menu?.findItem(R.id.searchMessageMenuItem)?.actionView as SearchView
        searchView?.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
            override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
                if (!query.isNullOrEmpty() && validateQuery(query))
                    searchViewModel.searchMessage(query)
                return true
            }

            override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean { return true }
        })
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }
```

So when i click on the seach icon the keyboard comes up and the toolbar sets up for write.
Well, i want this functionality to happen as default when the activity starts, and not by clicking the search icon. I have tried `searchView.requestFocus()` but this does not work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you need is set the `app:showAsAction ="always"` in your menu.xml

and on your on `onCreateOptionsMenu` use `searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false)` to keep the searchView expended by default.

This does not open the keyboard, it remains that Created this function to open the keyboard:

```
private fun setFocused(searchView: SearchView) {
    searchView.requestFocus()
    val imm = getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    imm.showSoftInput(searchView, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT)
}
```

and this is the complete Code :

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.search_message_menu, menu)
    searchView = menu?.findItem(R.id.searchMessageMenuItem)?.actionView as SearchView
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false)
    setFocused(searchView)
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
        override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
            /*
             * your code here
             */
            return true
        }

        override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
            return true
        }
    })
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
}


private fun setFocused(searchView: SearchView) {
    searchView.requestFocus()
    val imm = getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    imm.showSoftInput(searchView, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT)
}
```

and this is the menu :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/searchMessageMenuItem"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"

        android:title="Search"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView" />

</menu>
```

### UPDATE

For the icon which is always displayed I found this solution which can be useful I tried to hide the icon at one at the menu is created but the icon becomes visible when you click on the searchview (Redrawn) so i forced the icon to be hidden when the search view is redrawn and this my solution:

```
 searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false)


 searchView.viewTreeObserver.addOnDrawListener {
            searchView.findViewById<AppCompatImageView>(androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_button).visibility = View.GONE
            searchView.findViewById<AppCompatImageView>(androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_mag_icon).visibility = View.GONE
        }
 setFocused(searchView)
```

and also if you want te keep the close icon visible when the query is empty you can use :

```
searchView.findViewById<AppCompatImageView>(androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_close_btn).visibility = View.VISIBLE
```

Comment: Check the answer that i wrote below, maybe you can help me

Comment: do you want to hide it at all ? @james04

Comment: I want the layout to be as the second image exactly, but to expand automatically when i enter the activity